# Home network advice - How do I connect 2 ISP modem devices to router?

Tags: networking, routing

I would like some recommendations on this configuration.

2 links (ISP bridge) > CAT6 => Switch or router ???? => 900 feet (fiber) => udmp => L2 switch > devices

How do I connect 2 ISP modem devices to udmp? From udmp to devices are working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any Linux device such as a Raspberry Pi, with USB ethernet, or any router running OpenWRT, or a Mikrotik Routerboard. Then you can set up DHCP on each of those interfaces, but just put a higher metric on the route you want to use as backup.

Or you can employ different NAT or routing algorithms to decide how you want the traffic to be split.

For example ISP1 might give you 192.168.1.2 with gateway 192.168.1.1 and ISP2 might give you 192.168.2.2 with gateway 192.168.2.1, and you will have a DHCP server on your LAN bridge that hands out 192.168.3.0/24 with 192.168.3.1 on your router and your other devices getting addresses in that range with 192.168.3.1 as the gateway.

You will enable NAT on your router, so that your 192.168.3.0/24 devices can get routed through either ISP, but it will go through the one with the lowest "distance" or metric.  Or you can use masquerade rules to mark certain traffic to use one gateway, or the other, or to do it round robin or based on hashing of the address, lots of ways. Look for "multi homing" to learn more.

Comment: `a Raspberry Pi, with USB ethernet` - how will this connect to the fiber?

Comment: Ethernet socket. If you have SFP's you can get SFP to Ethernet adapters.

Comment: You know, USB ethernet on raspberry pi 4 can barely handle 1 gigabit .... so ...

Comment: It can do 600Mbps. The perceptual difference in internet speed between 100Mbps and 500Mbps is barely noticeable to 99.9999% of people. Use a Pi5 then. Or Mikrotik RB.